# How to format comment from bold to normal with win32?

Tags: python, excel

I just added a comment to a cell in an excel file. And somehow it turned out in bold, which I don't want. What can I do to fix it?

My code:

```
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
file_location = 'C:\Users\A42918\Desktop\Test_folder\Abild, T1.xls'
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(file_location)

ws = wb.Worksheets("Trelindad_utan")
ws.Range('AH4').Interior.ColorIndex = 37
ws.Range('AH4').Font.Bold = True
comment = 'E14678: Vinkel i nollpunkt. Sätts lika med vinkeln på I-bus i balansnätet (om denna avviker mycket från noll grader).'.decode('utf-8')
ws.Range('AH4').AddComment(comment)
cmt = ws.Range('AH4').AddComment(comment)

cmt.Shape.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Bold = False 

wb.SaveAs(Filename = 'C:\Users\A42918\Desktop\color_resultat.xls')

excel.Application.Quit()
```

This gives me the error message:     cmt.Shape.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Bold = False 
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'Font'

What does that mean?

Comment: You are correct that the line `ws.Range('AH4').Font.Bold = True` originally made the contents of the cell bold. But assuming you have saved the changes to the file, removing the line of code won't change the cell font weight back to normal. You need to include the line `ws.Range('AH4').Font.Bold = False`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you need to deal with the `Comment` object. The `Range` object representing cell "AH4" is independently formatted; changing the font formatting (e.g., bold) on the cell will not have any effect on the comment.

This should resolve it:

```
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
file_location = 'C:\Users\A42918\Desktop\Test_folder\Abild, T1.xls'
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(file_location)

ws = wb.Worksheets("Trelindad_utan")
ws.Range('AH4').Interior.ColorIndex = 37
ws.Range('AH4').Font.Bold = True
comment = 'E14678: Vinkel i nollpunkt. Sätts lika med vinkeln på I-bus i balansnätet (om denna avviker mycket från noll grader).'.decode('utf-8')
# remove any previous comments just in case
ws.Range('AH4').ClearComments 
# Add the comment, and its text:
cmt = ws.Range('AH4').AddComment(comment)
# Ensure the comment is not bolded font
cmt.Shape.TextFrame.Characters().Font.Bold = False
```

Comment: This code doesn't work for me. I get this error message : AttributeError: 'function' has no attribute 'Font'. It seems that comments are bold by default. Any suggestions how to solve it? Do you know of any win32 documentations?

Comment: @Roslund please revise your question to include the code you're currently using, and the full traceback.

Comment: Try adding parens after the `.Characters`, my answer revised accordingly.

Comment: As for "documentation", almost everything you do with Win32Com will very closely follow the object model reference (just google VBA Excel Object Model or something like that). Differences will be minimal, usually, like in this case where python required the parentheses after `.Characters`.

Answer (score 1):

This solves my problem!

```
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
file_location = 'C:\Users\A42918\Desktop\Test_folder\Abild, T1.xls'
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(file_location)

ws = wb.Worksheets("Trelindad_utan")
ws.Range('AH4').Interior.ColorIndex = 37 
ws.Range('AH4').Font.Bold = True

ws.Range('AH4').ClearComments 
comment = 'E14678: Vinkel i nollpunkt. Sätts lika med vinkeln på I-bus i balansnätet (om denna avviker mycket från noll grader).'.decode('utf-8')

cmt = ws.Range('AH4').AddComment(comment)

cmt.Shape.TextFrame.Characters().Font.Bold = False 

wb.SaveAs(Filename = 'C:\Users\A42918\Desktop\color_resultat.xls')

excel.Application.Quit()
```